# Call script after gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have started to work with gitlab ci and I am still new to CI in general. I currently want to call a script after a successful test build of my master branch. This script will notify my server to do a pull, build and restart.
I can not use kubernetes or docker, as the project lead doesn't want to use them.
I can do the scipt and such, but the gitlab ci config documentation is confusing and I cant seem to find an option on how to call the script after it finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid of me asking. Its as simple as defining a new stage after the last stage and call the script there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a simple task at the end of a pipeline, try the `after_script` directive. There is also a `before_script` counterpart.

Docs at:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script